# Event handler running and activated but not receiving

Tags: event-handlers, events

I have installed an event handler to catch ItemAdded and change the content type if the item is a folder.  I have installed and deployed this solution using a WSP and have activated it, but it doesn't seem to be running.  I'm not getting any of my messages written to the event log, so it looks like it's not running at all.  I installed Sharepoint Event Handler Manager to check on what event handlers are running and i'm not seeing my event running on the site.  The event handler runs on the whole site, so I'm not sure where i go to check to see whether it's running or not in the event handler manager..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio set a breakpoint on the first line of your method and attach to the w3wp process.

Comment: Hi again Laurie - This solution was built with visual studio 2010 and we only have 2008 on the development server.  Any other suggestions?  Thank you!

Comment: I re-created the solution in 2008 and have attached the debugger to the w3wp process, but when I add an item to the list, it doesn't hit the breakpoint

Comment: Not sure if you're following along but I got the breakpoint to hit, but SPListItem listItem = properties.ListItem; - listItem is null at this point.  This worked fine before I set up the deployment package..

Comment: Is listItem still null after you step to the next line of code? If so, is it possible that you are using Windows Explorer to upload your document?